# Зная вершины, связать их в единый граф, так чтобы к каждой был доступ

Tags: python, алгоритм, графы, процедурная-генерация

У меня есть список комнат (прямоугольников с координатами левого верхнего угла и длин их сторон), который рандомно создается, а комнаты не пересекаются. Нужно создать соединения между этими вершинами, будущего графа и сам граф, так чтобы это соединения были горизонтальными или вертикальными прямыми.

Я пытался искать ближайшие комнаты по расстоянию до них и пересечению по одной из координат (для двух горизонтально расположенных комнат, по у). Он находит ближайшую, но может через уже соединенную (дейстительно ближайшую) провести путь до другой "ближайшей" (см. рис)
[image: Пример]

ПЫСЫ: Я создаю поземелье для игры, с комнатами все окей, а вот соединения...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Гарантируется ли, что решение существует? Например, если на этом рисунке комнату 3 подвинуть левее, а 2 - правее, то ничего не выйдет.

Comment: Гарантируется, алгоритм генерации это обеспечивает.

Comment: По идее, можно сначала проводить одни лишь вертикальные (или горизонтальные) проходы, получится несколько компонент связности, которые, скорее всего, можно будет соединить несколькими горизонтальными проходами. Но тут проблема в том, что получившееся подземелье будет выглядеть странновато. Вероятно, надо стремиться к тому, чтобы количество вертикальных и горизонтальных проходов примерно совпадало.

Comment: Другая идея - сразу при генерации комнаты генерировать и выходящие из нее проходы, а новые комнаты - генерировать на концах этих проходов.

Comment: Слышал про Триангуляцию Делоне, вроде на ее основе можно что-то подобное делать, но как она работает и как использовать - понятия не имею